# Equivalent of mslice[] in matlab to python?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I've been given some MatLab code and I'm trying to write it in Python. However, I've searched online and I cannot find an equivalent or even documentation for the MatLab (I'm assuming) method 'mslice'. For context, I'm doing image analysis with cv2, numpy, and matplotlib. I'm pretty new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

```
for i in mslice[1:VC.NumObjects]:
    ii = numel(VC.PixelIdxList(i))
    if ii <= 10:
        BWvtemo(VC.PixelIdxList(i)).lvalue = 0
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you expect `mslice` would do (by providing input and output data, along with an explanation)? I can't find any reference to it, and we can't help you recreate its functionality in Python if we don't know what it does.

Comment: Could you post the original MATLAB code? Could `mslice` have been a *variable*?

Comment: I don't have MatLab, so I don't know what the output would look like, and unfortunately the person who provided this code did not document. I think it is supposed to create intervals between the first index and the last index of CC, although I could be wrong.

Comment: @gnovice In the original code, mslice is not mentioned anywhere but this loop. I don't actually have the original MatLab code, I believe this code has been run through a converter but not fully converted to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some emailing and some researching around, I've found my answer, so I'm just posting it here for others who might have my problem. mslice is a method is not defined outside the OMPC matlab to python converter. A similar method one could use would be the `range()` function or the numpy function `arange()` for non integer values. Thanks to everyone who helped!